# PHP loop through array of object gives unexpected result

Tags: php, loops, object, reference

I have the following PHP code to set parentId for each post.
The parentId of each data all become the last post ID.
What's wrong with my logic?

btw, if I change it to array, everythings becomes ok. Please help!

```
$data = array(
    (object)array('name' => 'myname')
);
$posts = array(
    (object)array('ID' => 1, 'data'=>$data),
    (object)array('ID' => 2, 'data'=>$data),
    (object)array('ID' => 3, 'data'=>$data)
);
foreach($posts as &$post){
    $post->data[0]->parentId = $post->ID;
}
print '<pre>';print_r($posts);die;
die;
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => myname
                            [parentId] => 3 // expect to be 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => myname
                            [parentId] => 3 // expect to be 2 !!!
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => myname
                            [parentId] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: try this http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yq2-jv3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All things considered, the *real* issue here is, after a second glance at your code, the way you're setting the `data` property. Since PHP5, objects are passed/assigned *by reference* by default. Remember the PHP4 days? (`$newInstance = &new SomeClass();`), PHP5 uses references for objects now, so when you do:

```
$data = array(
    (object)array('name' => 'myname')//create object
);
```

Then, all three objects are assigned the same object (By *reference!*), so if you change it for the first time around, all three instances will reflect the same change!

[I've recently posted a lengthy answer on references in loops here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459521/what-is-better-in-a-foreach-loop-using-the-symbol-or-reassigning-based-on-k/18464019#18464019), it might be worth a look, because looping by reference isn't the best way to go about your business.

*Some code-review:*
Instead of constructing all these arrays, and cast them to objects individually, I'd just do this:

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'myname')
);
$posts = array(
    array('ID' => 1, 'data'=>$data),
    array('ID' => 2, 'data'=>$data),
    array('ID' => 3, 'data'=>$data)
);
foreach($posts as $k => $post)
{
    $posts[$k]['data'][0]['parentId'] = $posts[$k]['ID'];
}
$posts = json_decode(json_encode($posts));//turns everything into objects
print_r($posts);
```

At first, it might seem inefficient to `json_encode` something, just to `json_decode` it, but `json_decode` returns objects, instead of associative arrays by default. I've ran a few tests scripts not too long ago, as it turned out: the encode-decode approach was actually faster than casting each associative array...

Answer (score 3):

Okay, i misunderstood your problem, due to the fact that you reuse the data object you end up with a reference problem, this can be avoided by using clone, as seen below

```
<?php

$data = (object) array('name' => 'myname');

$posts = array(
    (object) array('ID' => 1, 'data'=> array(clone $data)),
    (object) array('ID' => 2, 'data'=> array(clone $data)),
    (object) array('ID' => 3, 'data'=> array(clone $data))
);

foreach($posts as $postKey => $post){
    $posts[$postKey]->data[0]->parentId = $posts[$postKey]->ID;
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($posts);
```

Comment: you're wrong he makes a pass by reference, therefore he's working on the data inside the array

Comment: rather then cloning, not using objects until after the data property has been assigned its values is _way_ more performant and a lot easier, too

Comment: yes - i just didn't wanted to change the ingoing data for this example, if you of course can avoid all this mix between objects and and arrays in the first place – even better