# Converting string of datetime to array with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, arrays, date, time

I have this date and time string

> 2013-10-21 09:49:51 2013-10-22 10:23:06 2013-10-22 10:23:20 2013-10-22 10:33:34 2013-10-22 10:33:40 2013-10-23 15:14:04 2013-10-23 15:14:09 2013-10-23 15:15:04 2013-10-23 15:26:18 2013-10-23 15:27:26 2013-10-23 15:27:29 2013-10-23 15:37:16 2013-10-23 15:45:08 2013-10-23 15:47:19 2013-10-23 16:05:37 2013-10-23 16:23:28 2013-10-23 16:31:09 2013-10-23 16:32:08 2013-10-23 16:32:54 2013-10-23 17:11:28 2013-10-23 17:12:24 2013-10-23 17:12:33 2013-10-23

I need some to help to process string into array using `preg_match`.

Example of the expected output array:

```
datetimeArr=array(0=>'2013-10-21 09:49:51',1=>'2013-10-22 10:23:06',2=>'2013-10-23 15:45:08')
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you have to use a regex:

```
.{10}\s.{8}
```

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/aU6bL4

Answer (score 0):

Have fun doing that with RegEx. I would just explode the string at the position of 2013. Then you can add it into an array easiely.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a regular expression here, just use [`str_split`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) since your chunks are fixed-length:

```
$dtStrings = "2013-10-21 09:49:51 2013-10-22 10:23:06 2013-10-22 10:23:20 2013-10-22 10:33:34 2013-10-22 10:33:40 2013-10-23 15:14:04 2013-10-23 15:14:09 2013-10-23 15:15:04 2013-10-23 15:26:18 2013-10-23 15:27:26 2013-10-23 15:27:29 2013-10-23 15:37:16 2013-10-23 15:45:08 2013-10-23 15:47:19 2013-10-23 16:05:37 2013-10-23 16:23:28 2013-10-23 16:31:09 2013-10-23 16:32:08 2013-10-23 16:32:54 2013-10-23 17:11:28 2013-10-23 17:12:24 2013-10-23 17:12:33 2013-10-23";

$dtArray = str_split($dtStrings, 20);
```

Of course you're going to have a trailing whitespace character in each element (except maybe the last). To remove this, just loop through the array running [`rtrim`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) on the elements.

```
$dtArray = array_map('trim', str_split($dtStrings, 20));
```

Comment: Please, avoid looping over an array by reference. Dangling references are just accidents waiting to happen. [More details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18464019/1230836)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Very interesting! Thanks for pointing me to learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '2013-10-21 09:49:51 2013-10-22 10:23:06 2013-10-22 10:23:20 2013-10-22 10:33:34 2013-10-22 10:33:40 2013-10-23 15:14:04 2013-10-23 15:14:09 2013-10-23 15:15:04 2013-10-23 15:26:18 2013-10-23 15:27:26 2013-10-23 15:27:29 2013-10-23 15:37:16 2013-10-23 15:45:08 2013-10-23 15:47:19 2013-10-23 16:05:37 2013-10-23 16:23:28 2013-10-23 16:31:09 2013-10-23 16:32:08 2013-10-23 16:32:54 2013-10-23 17:11:28 2013-10-23 17:12:24 2013-10-23 17:12:33 2013-10-23';

preg_match_all('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/', $input, $output_array);
var_dump($output_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really NEED to use regular expressions, the simplest one would be:

```
preg_match_all('/(.{19})\s?/', $input, $result);
$result = $result[1];
```

Otherwise it is better to use this one-line solution since regexp is an overkill for this task:

```
$result = array_map('trim', str_split($input, 20));
```