# Set a variable's value after it's declared

Tags: php

I do like this: These are my menus items:

```
$menu = 'View archives for '.$year;

$year = 2013; //Note that `$year` is set after the above.
```

Without making any changes, how can I do something like this (set a variables value later)?

I was trying this, which failed.

```
$menu = 'View archives for '. &$year;

$year = '2013';
```

Comment: You can't call a variable that hasn't yet been declared unless it's stored from a previous session.

Comment: This is plain wrong, you can't do it like that!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: If this is just about `$menu`, why don't you update it after updating `$year`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to do this, is by using a reference, but that's going to make your code into an unholy, unmaintainable, error-prone minefield. [Read this if you don't know why references are dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459521/what-is-better-in-a-foreach-loop-using-the-symbol-or-reassigning-based-on-k/18464019#18464019)
Still, you're free to try it if you want to:

```
$year = null;
$menu = array('View archives for ', &$year);//pass reference to $year
$year = '2013';
echo implode('', $menu);
```

As you can see, I still have to define the variable before I can pass a reference too it (du'h, you can't reference what is about to exist, only what exists).
Once you've done that, you can assign any value that takes your whim to `$year`, and automatically, the second value in the `$menu` array will follow, because it just references the `$year` variable.

Still, if the snippet in your question is all you're trying to do, why not use `sprintf`?

```
$menu = 'View archives for %s';
//some code
$year = '2013';
$menu = sprintf($menu, $year);
echo $menu;//sure enough: View archives for 2013
```

As an added bonus, you can use this in a loop over and over again:

```
$format = 'View archives for %s';
for ($i=2010;$i<2014;++$i)
{
    printf($format, $i);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

This prints:

```
View archives for 2010
View archives for 2011
View archives for 2012
View archives for 2013
```

Easy, once you've [read through the manual of `printf` and related functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: Is it not possible to do this without the array, by just using a string as I have done above?

Comment: Because it's not just the year, there's other stuff as well

Comment: @jmenezes: No, because you concatenate a value into a new string. This creates a new string, and strings cannot reference a variable. They are _constant_ A string is a string, and a string is _constant_. A variable, as the name suggests, is variable by definition... You either use an array, or you use a format string, with placeholders... that's what they're for

Comment: @jmenezes: If it's other stuff, you'll have to use a format, or concatenate on the spot: `printf("Item %d -> %s: %d", 1, 'View archives for', 2013);` uses 3 placeholders, and prints _"Item 1 -> View archives for: 2013"_ use as many as you like...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The definition of `$year` must precede the definition of anything that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept of program flow is that you must declare the value of a variable before you can use it. There are other software concepts (flow programming) where code doesn't execute until all its inputs exist - but php is not that language.

The only solution is to initialize the value of `$year` before you use it - change the order of the statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add year then this should do your work
 $menu = 'View archives for '.date('Y');
and it's not possible to use a variable before declaration