# How can I access an array dimension, based on another array?

Tags: php, arrays

Using the following code:

```
<?php
  $array = array(
    array(
      array('a','b'),
      array('c')
    )
  );
  $location = array('0','1');
  $text = 'd';
?>
```

How can I achieve the following, if the number of elements in `$location[]` is unknown?

```
$array[$location[0]][$location[1]][] = $text;
```

In other words, how do I go one dimension into `$array` for each element in `$location[]` and add $text there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers show, this *can* be achieved with references. However, references are a tad tricky, and can prove difficult to debug. When performing the same loop twice with different arrays, or when nesting loops, the results [can be rather baffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459521/what-is-better-in-a-foreach-loop-using-the-symbol-or-reassigning-based-on-k/18464019#18464019), not to mention that assigning by reference can in some cases also issue an `E_DEPRECATED` notice (not in this particular example, but you never know how your code will be used further down the line). I'd suggest using a recursive function, for that reason:

```
function getLocation(array $in, array $location)
{
    $in = $in[$location[0]];
    if (is_array($in) && count($location) > 1)
    {//more than 1 index left
        $location = array_slice($location,1);//or use unshift
        return getLocation($in, $location);
    }
    return $in;
}
```

That would be my suggestion: It's easy to read, understand and maintain
To add something to a given location, you can alter this function to recursively (re-)assign values:

```
function addToLocation(array $in, array $location, $value)
{
    if (count($location) === 1)
    {//optionally add is_array checks
        $in[$location[0]][] = $value;
        return $in;
    }
    $in[$location[0]] = addToLocation(
                            $in[$location[0]],
                            array_slice($location, 1),
                            $value
    );
    return $in;
}
```

The up-sides:

- Easier to debug, use and maintain
- requires no greater skill set to use (the function signature says it all, really)
- safer (no references to tidy up, which is easily forgotten)
- recursion is fun :)

The down-sides/tradeoffs:

- recursion gives some extra overhead (larger call-stack, local scope stays in memory etc...)
- References are faster than accessing arrays by index (which requires a HashTable lookup, though these are *O(1)* operations, a reference gives you direct access, no lookup required)

As often: defensive code is slightly slower, and more resource intensive. The faster approach is more vulnerable, though and harder to maintain. The choice is yours.

Comment: Amazing! I was actually thinking of a recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

That can be achieved with:

```
  $array = array(
    array(
      array('a','b'),
      array('c')
    )
  );
  $location = array('0','1');
  $text = 'd';

$pointer = &$array;
foreach($location as $index)
{
   $pointer = &$pointer[$index];
}
$pointer[] = $text;
unset($pointer);//this is for safety
```

Last `unset` is needed - because if you'll forget to do that, you could end with debugging "mysterious" bugs when you'll later use `$pointer` somewhere in code (that will obviously have momentary side-effect, change your source data and cause bugs, while whole logic will be ok)

Comment: Please be weary of reference-variables... perhaps add an `unset` statement, and explain the necessity for it

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem in that you're correct - that may be painful to debug. Updated

Answer (score 2):

To read:

```
$value = $array;
foreach ($location as $index) {
    $value = $value[$index];
}
```

To write:

```
$value =& $array;
foreach ($location as $index) {
    if (!array_key_exists($value, $index)) {
        $value[$index] = array();
    }
    $value =& $value[$index];
}
$value[] = $text;
```

Comment: Doubt. Op wants dynamic de-reference

Comment: Yep, I noticed. Added that.

Comment: @Oswald: Same comment - references can lead to mysterious bugs that are hard to track down and fix, please add an `unset` + explanation to complete your answer (I've added a link to an answer, explaining the dangers of references that aren't unset properly to my answer, check that if you're not clear on what I'm on about)