# I need a shorter way to compare variables?

Tags: php

Okay I have 15 variables $A - $O. I need a different way to compare the variables as I think I am doing this a really long way. It works the way I want it to but I'm not happy with the amount of code.

So what my code is doing it's generating a random number for each of the variables. I have it doing this while they equal each other, so in other words it will stop generating random number when each of the variables is different here is my code... Thanks in advance.

```
    do{
$a = rand($min,$max);
$b = rand($min,$max);
$c = rand($min,$max);
$d = rand($min,$max);
$e = rand($min,$max);
$f = rand($min,$max);
$g = rand($min,$max);
$h = rand($min,$max);
$i = rand($min,$max);
$j = rand($min,$max);
$k = rand($min,$max);
$l = rand($min,$max);
$m = rand($min,$max);
$n = rand($min,$max);
$o = rand($min,$max);
}

while ($a==$b || $a==$c || $a==$d || $a==$e || $a==$f || $a==$g || $a==$h || $a==$i || $a==$j || $a==$k || $a==$l || $a==$m || $a==$n || $a==$o
       || $b==$a || $b==$c || $b==$d || $b==$e || $b==$f || $b==$g || $b==$h || $b==$i || $b==$j || $b==$k || $b==$l || $b==$m || $b==$n || $b==$o
       || $c==$a || $c==$b || $c==$d || $c==$e || $c==$f || $c==$g || $c==$h || $c==$i || $c==$j || $c==$k || $c==$l || $c==$m || $c==$n || $c==$o 
       || $d==$a || $d==$b || $d==$c || $d==$e || $d==$f || $d==$g || $d==$h || $d==$i || $d==$j || $d==$k || $d==$l || $d==$m || $d==$n || $d==$o 
       || $e==$a || $e==$b || $e==$c || $e==$d || $e==$f || $e==$g || $e==$h || $e==$i || $e==$j || $e==$k || $e==$l || $e==$m || $e==$n || $e==$o 
       || $f==$a || $f==$b || $f==$c || $f==$d || $f==$e || $f==$g || $f==$h || $f==$i || $f==$j || $f==$k || $f==$l || $f==$m || $f==$n || $f==$o 
       || $g==$a || $g==$b || $g==$c || $g==$d || $g==$e || $g==$f || $g==$h || $g==$i || $g==$j || $g==$k || $g==$l || $g==$m || $g==$n || $g==$o 
       || $h==$a || $h==$b || $h==$c || $h==$d || $h==$e || $h==$f || $h==$g || $h==$i || $h==$j || $h==$k || $h==$l || $h==$m || $h==$n || $h==$o 
       || $i==$a || $i==$b || $i==$c || $i==$d || $i==$e || $i==$f || $i==$g || $i==$h || $i==$j || $i==$k || $i==$l || $i==$m || $i==$n || $i==$o 
       || $j==$a || $j==$b || $j==$c || $j==$d || $j==$e || $j==$f || $j==$g || $j==$h || $j==$i || $j==$k || $j==$l || $j==$m || $j==$n || $j==$o 
       || $k==$a || $k==$b || $k==$c || $k==$d || $k==$e || $k==$f || $k==$g || $k==$h || $k==$i || $k==$j || $k==$l || $k==$m || $k==$n || $k==$o 
       || $l==$a || $l==$b || $l==$c || $l==$d || $l==$e || $l==$f || $l==$g || $l==$h || $l==$i || $l==$j || $l==$k || $l==$m || $l==$n || $l==$o 
       || $m==$a || $m==$b || $m==$c || $m==$d || $m==$e || $m==$f || $m==$g || $m==$h || $m==$i || $m==$j || $m==$k || $m==$l || $m==$n || $m==$o 
       || $n==$a || $n==$b || $n==$c || $n==$d || $n==$e || $n==$f || $n==$g || $n==$h || $n==$i || $n==$j || $n==$k || $n==$l || $n==$m || $n==$o 
       || $o==$a || $o==$b || $o==$c || $o==$d || $o==$e || $o==$f || $o==$g || $o==$h || $o==$i || $o==$j || $o==$k || $o==$l || $o==$m || $o==$n
       );
```

Comment: You've already checked if $a==$j (for example), so why check if $j==$a ?

Comment: Yeah I have done that in a few places but that really isn't what I'm asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with an array:

```
$randoms = array();
while(count($randoms) < 15)
{
    $randoms[] = mt_rand($min, $max);//add random
    $randoms = array_unique($randoms);//remove duplicates
}
$randoms = array_combine(range('a', 'o'), $randoms);//set keys a to o
```

And if you *really*, ***Really*** want those values as separate variables, you can do this using [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
foreach ($randoms as $letter => $val)
{
    $$letter = $val;
}
```

Because I wrote `$$letter` (note two `$` signs), this expression evaluates to `$<value of $letter>` or `$a`, `$b` and so on, to which I assign the corresponding value

I suppose, if you want to get the best performance for the least amount of code/overhead, this would be the way to get it:

```
$random = array();
$count = 0;
$rand = null;
while($count < 15)
{
    $rand = mt_rand($min, $max);
    if (!isset($random[$rand]))
    {//assign random value, and use keys for faster lookup
        ++$count;
        $random[$rand] = $rand;
    }
}
var_dump($random);//guaranteed to hold 15 random values, both the keys and values
//so:
$vals = array_values($random);//or array_keys($random)
```

And again, to turn this array into a distinct variables:

```
$arr = array_combine(range('a', 'o'), array_values($random));
//or even array_combine(range('a', 'o'), $random);
foreach ($arr as $name => $val)
    $$name = $val;
```

Comment: Your edited code is a clever approach. Really smart. Have my vote.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use variables to access other variables by names in strings.

For instance you can do something like that in your case:

```
$names = array('a','b','c','d'); // And so on - it can be done easier with casting to char

function check_names_equal($names) {
    foreach($names as $name) {
        global $$name;
    }
    foreach($names as $name) {
        foreach($names as $name2) {
            if ($name != $name2 && $$name == $$name2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

while(check_names_equal($names)); // <- this is your shortened while
```

My comment to that - I know it's not the perfect way to that and I would suggest that you use arrays for holding variables, don't store some random data in single variables.

Your start of the code should like like this prefferably: (it would better to use numbers as indexes too, so you can use loops)

```
$arr = array();
$arr['a'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['b'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['c'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['d'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['e'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['f'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['g'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['h'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['i'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['j'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['k'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['l'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['m'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['n'] = rand($min,$max);
$arr['o'] = rand($min,$max);
```

And with numeric indexing:

```
$arr=array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[] = rand($min,$max);
}
```

Comment: _"unlike most of the languages"_? Based on what are you making that claim? Python, C#, RoR,... there's a lot of languages that support this. Also using `global $$name` is just all shades of wrong.

Comment: I know it's wrong, but how should I respond to this question? I don't know what exactly Trevor Keating wanted and I tried pointing out that there are some ways to make it faster with some functions or loop usage. And about calling variables by string - is it really that easy to do that in C# for example? I just didn't see any other language which has it so simple like PHP do, maybe my statement was wrong then.

Comment: @KeluThatsall: _as easy as_ is relative. People who are used to writing Java find reflection and `Map` not that hard. C# and python have dictionaries, which allow you to do the same thing, and even JS (`window[strVarNameVar]`) makes it insanely easy: basically, every non-compiled language supports this (one way or another, if only through `eval`), and byte-code compiled languages often do, too

Comment: okay didn't know that, thanks for clarifying :) But I would argue that using Map or Dictionary is as easy as using `$$name`. I wasn't talking about named indexes in arrays.

Comment: @KeluThatsall: I know, that's why I said _as easy as_ is a relative thing. Java is all-objects anyway, so implement a lookup function in a given class that relies on a map would work... it's just: the people writing in those languages are used to things working that way, and perhaps they'd find `$$varVal` to be hard to read, difficult to follow and just, generally, a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $min = 0;
    $min = 999;
    while (count($array) < 16){
        $val = rand($min,$max);
        if (!in_array($val, $array)) {
            $array[] = $val;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the variables to an array and then perform your do-while as such:

```
$arr = array(&$a, &$b, &$c, &$d);

do {
    foreach ($arr as $i => $k)
        $arr[$i] = rand($min, $max);
}
while (count($arr) == array_unique($arr));
```

But in your example you are re-doing a lot of work that is not needed, e.g do not re-random unique values. Just a tip.

Comment: This is _not_ the easiest way, and [is even dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459521/what-is-better-in-a-foreach-loop-using-the-symbol-or-reassigning-based-on-k/18464019#18464019) in some ways. Don't use references unless you _really_ have to. In this case, you don't, especially because you're nesting loops

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem References sure are needed, just not as you described in the nested for-each. I still stand by my answer that this is the easiest way, since it will be more applicable. I updated my answer.

Comment: You're missing the point: references are _dangerous_ (and read my answer: you can get rid of them and _still_ see random values assigned to separate values). Also: `someFunction(&$passByRef);` will issue an `E_DEPRECATED` notice. Not sure about `array(&$a);` but I wouldn't be surprized to learn that triggers the same notice, too. And even if it didn't: what if I add lines after your code that read like this: `$b = reset($arr); $a = 'foo';` What would happen to `$b`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The pass-by-reference is only deprecated from a callers point of view for functions.

Comment: that's why I said I wasn't sure if constructing an array would issue a notice: but you're using references without even _warning_ the OP about any of the risks. Bare in mind that the OP's question doesn't suggest he's even aware of their being such a thing as references. That's like giving a baby a gun: it might take it for a toy or lolly-pop...

Answer (score 0):

Ahother option is to create an array and go growing it with random values comparing every new vaue with the existing ones:

```
$myvars=array();
while (sizeof($myvars)<15)
{
    $success=false;
    do{
        $candidate=rand($min,$max);
        //compare the candidate with every element in array
        if (!in_array($candidate, $myvars))
            $success=true; //if found no success
    } while (!$success);
    $myvars[]=$candidate;
```

}

Now in `$myvars` you have 15 different values.

Comment: Wow, nested 3 levels deep, `while` -> `do...while` -> `foreach`. see my answer: 1 loop, containting 2 lines of code: does exactly the same

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem you are right. I've changed it to use `in_array`. What I meant with my answer is that the solutions has to be fast, so creating elements one by one will be better than creating every element and do the comparision. Your approach is a little different because you create the element, put it into the array and the call `array_unique`. The interesting question is: what will be more efficient with a bigger amount of data?

Comment: I'm quite sure that this isn't as fast as you think it is. I'll add a faster version to my answer in a moment, and you're still nesting loops: no need. The wider the range, the less chance of duplicates you have anyway, and checking might not be required. But even if you do: `in_array` is a function call `isset` is a language construct -> faster

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem What is the complexity of `array_unique`? I'm not sure it is as fast as you think. We could do some `benchmarking`, just for fun :D

Comment: `in_array` is _O(n)_, whereas `array_unique` is closer to _O(log n)_. But in an array of 15 elements, the reality will be that both perform about the same. The edit to my answer uses the _keys_ of the array (PHP arrays being HashTables + `isset` being a language construct makes `isset($arr[$key]))`) which results in a time-complexity of (virtually) _O(1)_.