# Alternative to foreach pass by reference

Tags: php, foreach, pass-by-reference

I've come by a case where values in a foreach are passed by reference in order to modify the element, then at a later stage in the code, the same array is looped again to do some calculation but this time the elements are passed by value. The issue is that PHP retains the reference to the last element in the array in the first foreach, then *overwrites* that element when the next foreach starts if the local variable has the same name.

Example code:

```
<?php
$a = array("a" => "foo");
$b = array("b" => "bar");

$x = array($a, $b);

foreach ($x as &$y) {}

print_r($x);

foreach ($x as $y) {}

print_r($x);
?>
```

This will yield

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [b] => bar
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => foo
        )

)
```

This absurdity is stated in the PHP manual

> **Warning** Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

And indeed, using `unset($y)` will resolve the issue. But this is very fragile and you cannot rely on the coder always remembering to unset a variable which scope isn't obvious. So my question is: Are there any good alternatives to foreach-pass-by-reference that eliminates the need to unset the variable afterwards?

Comment: The example you gave doesn't give any clue on why it's necessary to use reference here.

Comment: `$a = array("a" => "foo"); $b = array("b" => "bar"); $x = array($a, $b);` are you sure you don't want to use `array_merge();`?

Comment: @raina77ow Is that really relevant? The code just points out the flaw. All you need to know is that the variable needs to be modified.

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 `array_merge()` is indeed better, but it doesn't change the behavior of the code.

Comment: I am <40% sure, but the `$x = array($a, $b);` makes the array 3 dimensional as it is now `$x = array(array("a" => "foo"), array("b" => "bar"));`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is better in a foreach loop... using the & symbol or reassigning based on key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459521/what-is-better-in-a-foreach-loop-using-the-symbol-or-reassigning-based-on-k)

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 That is correct. But it doesn't matter if the array is n dimensional. The value still gets overwritten.

Comment: The short answer: don't `foreach` by reference... unless you _really_ have to (which is a rare thing anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk):

```
array_walk($x, function(&$y) {
    /* ... */
});
```

This makes the reference `$y` local to the scope of the callback function so that unsetting is handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up using. Also worth noting is that for external variables to be avalible in the anonymous funcion, one must use [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASSOCIATIVE (indexed) foreach:

```
foreach ($x as $index=>$y)
{
 if ($y=='remove') {unset($x[$index]);}
}
```

This way you can modify the original array elements easily ...

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 No, he asked for "Alternative to foreach pass by reference". This is a valid answer.