# PHP - dynamically add dimensions to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a :

```
$value = "val";
```

I also have an array :

```
$keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'...]
```

The keys in that array are dynamically generated, and can go from 2 to 10 or more entries.

My goal is getting this :

```
$array['key1']['key2']['key3']... = $value;
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest, and least messy way (ie not using references) would be to use a recursive function:

```
function addArrayLevels(array $keys, array $target)
{
      if ($keys) {
          $key = array_shift($keys);
          $target[$key] = addArrayLevels($keys, []);
      }
      return $target;
}

//usage
$keys = range(1, 10);
$subArrays = addARrayLevels($keys, []);
```

It works [as you can see here](https://eval.in/430593).

*How* it works is really quite simple:

- `if ($keys) {`: if there's a key left to be added
- `$key = array_shift($keys);` shift the first element from the array
- `$target[$key] = addArrayLevels($keys, []);`: add the index to `$target`, and call the same function again with `$keys` (after having removed the first value). These recursive calls will go on until `$keys` is empty, and the function simply returns an empty array

The downsides:

- Recursion *can* be tricky to get your head round at first, especially in complex functions, in code you didn't write, but document it well and you should be fine

The pro's:

- It's more flexible (you can use `$target` as a sort of default/final assignment variable, with little effort (will add example below if I find the time)
- No [reference mess and risks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464019/1230836) to deal with

Example using adaptation of the function above to assign value at *"lowest"* level:

```
function addArrayLevels(array $keys, $value)
{
      $return = [];
      $key = array_shift($keys);
      if ($keys) {
          $return[$key] = addArrayLevels($keys, $value);
      } else {
          $return[$key] = $value;
      }
      return $return;
}

$keys = range(1, 10);
$subArrays = addARrayLevels($keys, 'innerValue');
var_dump($subArrays);
```

## [Demo](https://eval.in/430600)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that there is built-in function for that but you can do that with simple `foreach` and references.

```
$newArray = [];
$keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
$reference =& $newArray;

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $reference[$key] = [];

    $reference =& $reference[$key];
}

unset($reference);

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: @JeremyBelolo: Please read the linked answer in my _"pro's"_ list for an explanation, but believe me when I say: _avoid references when you can_, and you really can avoid them here